# Why datagrams are not numbered in UDP?

Tags: networking, udp

If user datagrams are not numbered(in UDP) then how the received data is ordered. Consider small applications involving small data transfers.

Comment: Because the protocol is designed that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a transport-layer protocol, UDP does not guarantee in-order delivery. For that, you would need to use a stream-based (transport-layer) protocol like TCP (or SCTP). UDP is a lightweight protocol by design and so does not offer in-order delivery. If the application wishes to have an in-order delivery, it would have to handle on its own.

The motivation behind a simpler design is true for other transport-layer properties as well, like retransmission, estimation of sending rate, and flow-control. UDP does not do any of these. Its simplicity leads to lower delay. Hence, as compared to TCP, UDP is more attractive for delay-sensitive applications like Audio/Video.

Comment: It has nothing to do with UDP being on the transport layer. TCP is on the transport layer too.

Comment: @user2357112 absolutely. Both of these protocols sit in the same layer and present two different options to applications.